# Запятая перед "как" в сравнительном обороте

Tags: запятые, сравнительный-оборот

Ну что ты как тряпка!

Ставится ли запятая перед "как"? Я думаю, что нет, потому что сравнительный оборот является частью сказуемого. Но лучше уточнить.Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ну что ты как тряпка!***

Это действительно сравнительный оборот в роли именной части сказуемого, связка в настоящем времени пропущена. Запятая в простом предложении не ставится, паузы нет.

***Ну что***  - это частица НУ  и вопросительное местоимение ЧТО (в значении "почему").

Здесь нет вопросительно-восклицательного сочетания, которое могло бы обособляться. https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129

Comment: Как всегда — предельно ясно и по делу. Вы делаете этот форум лучше, спасибо вам!

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь,  для меня очень важно ваше мнение.